# Vue2 custom event with native dom element

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have just started learning vue2. While playing with components and custom-event, i am facing a problem. I am expecting an alert with text **caught** but nothing happens. Below is the simple code:

```
<div class="container" id="app" >
    <div v-on:newmessage="handleNewMessage">
        <message></message>
    </div>        
</div>

<script>

    Vue.component('message',{
        template: '<input type="text" @keyup.enter="handleInput">',
        methods: {
            handleInput: function(event)
            {
                this.$emit('newmessage');
            },
        }
    });

    var demo = new Vue({
        el: '#app',

        methods: {
            handleNewMessage: function(message)
            {
                alert('caught');
            }
        },
    });


</script>
```

Please note that if i move the **newmessage** event listener from the **div** element to the **message** element, this works fine and the alert is generated:

```
 //this works
 <div >
     <message v-on:newmessage="handleNewMessage"></message>
</div>
```

I might as well be missing something very basic here. Do custom events not propagate up to native dom parent elements? I spent whole evening searching for a reference but no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it works as you explained since $emit is only visible at `<message>` tag (as I know it) and NOT at the `<div>` enclosing it. You can try directly emitting to the root component (#app) and wire the handler there too.

```
this.$root.$emit('newmessage')
```

and,

```
<div class="container" id="app" v-on:newmessage="handleNewMessage">
```

(EDIT)and,

```
const component = Vue.component('message' ...)

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: component
    ...)
```

Basically, you are not doing anything wrong here.

PS: I haven't run EDIT. But, the idea is along those lines. Let me know if that works.

Comment: `this.$root.$emit('newmessage')` does indeed emit the **newmessage** event but it cannot be caught at the root element with `<div class="container" id="app" v-on:newmessage="handleNewMessage">`.

Comment: oops, yes indeed since your vue component is NOT nested within the root instance. You can do that by adding a `components` to the root instance. Let me edit the answer.

Comment: Actually I want to catch the **newmessage** event right on the immediate outer div of my custom **message** component - `<div v-on:newmessage="handleNewMessage">
        <message></message>
    </div>` . <br /> Can you please tell how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Unlike components and props, event names will never be used as variable or property names in JavaScript, so there’s no reason to use camelCase or PascalCase. Additionally, v-on event listeners inside DOM templates will be automatically transformed to lowercase (due to HTML’s case-insensitivity), so v-on:myEvent would become v-on:myevent – making myEvent impossible to listen to.

For these reasons, we recommend you always use kebab-case for event names.